# Post data in header location with post method

Tags: php

We can send data to another file using header location:

```
header(location: payment.php?email=$email);
```

And receive:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

But as I want to send some important credential, I dont want to use `GET`. Is there any way to do it using POST?

I can not use session, so please ignore it

Comment: you can use autosubmit form

Comment: What abt encryption method?

Comment: What's your client? A browser? The "Location" header is also supposed to contain an _absolute_ URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this auto submit form

```
<?php
if(isset($email))
{
    ?>
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm"  action="payment.php" method="POST">
            <input name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" />
    </form>

    <script>
    function submitform()
    {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
    window.onload = submitform;
    </script>
<?php
}
    ?>
```